# Change the integer 1,2,3 with 01,02,03 of a month column to use pd.to_datetime etc

Tags: python

I have a column named as month in which month is given in the format 1,2,3,4.....9 etc. I want to replace them with 01,02,03,....09. I am currently using the code.

```
vals_to_replace = {'1':'01','2':'02','3':'03','4':'04','5':'05','6':'06','7':'07','8':'08','9':'09'} 

data['month'] = data['month'].map(vals_to_replace)
```

But after I am applying the map function, it is showing me nan values. Why it is happening .Please help

Comment: Arindam, this is not well posed question, give us some example what is in `data['month']`. My guess is that you try to use string replacement but in the `data['month']` are integers and not strings.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the month column in your dataframe comprises of integer values and you are mapping them to string values in the dictionary. Change it to integer values and it should work..